# What is the equivalent of CCS3 scale transform in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a css3 scale transform on hover, and I would like to recreate the effect for internet explorer users. Are there any smooth, similar functions to accomplish this? I looked at changing the width/height with percentages, but it didn't work well so I scraped that route.

Comment: Users of crappy browsers are not used to beautiful things, do not break your code to make it compatible for them. It will only confuse them.

Comment: You could either try [filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx) or perhaps the zoom property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that transforms do work on IE9 with the -ms prefix?

Otherwise, have a look at jQuery and the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.

Comment: Your original comment made me laugh though! :)

Comment: tks but I don't clame credit for it, speaker said that in a jQuery conference :)

Comment: Must have been an entertaining conference. I also agree with "if you can do it in CSS don't do it in JS", very true.

Comment: Yes I have been using -ms for IE9, I was thinking for IE7, IE8 (even though the number of users are shrinking, there are still a lot of them, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
zoom: 2; /* IE */
-moz-transform: scale(2); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari And Chrome */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Also if you can do it in CSS don't do it in JS. CSS is hardware acelerated while JS is not.

Or as Joe-R pointed out you can use "-ms" prefix. Check it here: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

```
-ms-transform: scale(2); /* Internet explorer*/
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Because of the way that CSS3 handles it (by scaling every child element in a contain object that you choose) it would be very difficult to make without CSS3. You can always change the width, height, and font-size of things, and even animate it.